# Recombination in genetic algorithm?

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I am writing an app using genetic algorithm, where I use two the genes of an individual are real numbers (doubles, since I am writing it in Java). So I was wondering what would be the best way to do the recombination using real numbers and not bits.

I tried doing it this way:

If `p1 = (x1, y1)` and `p2 = (x2, y2)` were parents and r was some random number between 0 and 1, then I would get the children like this:

```
c1 = (  r*x1   + (1-r)*x2 ,   r*y1   + (1-r)*y2)
c2 = ((1-r)*x1 +   r*x2   , (1-r)*y1 +   r*y2  )
```

But I am not very satisfied with the result this solution gives me. It seems that the children are not always better than the parents, but they should be based on the main concept of genetic algorithm.

So I would be grateful if anyone could give me another idea or a hint.

Comment: *"It seems that the children are not always better than the parents, but they should be based on the main concept of genetic algorithm"* - A guarantee that the offspring created by intermediate recombination are definitely better than both parents is only given in certain particular situations, e.g. if your function f : R² -> R to be minimized is strictly quasiconvex and f(p1) = f(p2). In the general case though there is no guarantee, just a good chance on average that the offspring is better.

Comment: When you define your children like that you will get only the "average" of your parents factors. Instead of getting the "better" value of the two parent factors, you just get some value in between the given values, basically its `(a+b)/2` with some variation. If you have a strong characterization of value `a` in one parent you will loose it for the next generation. You have no competition of your genes, so there is no "winner". What are your values `x` and `y` representing and how do you determine when your result is good or bad? How do you define "better" in your case you have?

Comment: @Progman `x` and `y` represent speed and angle under which a cannon shoots a ball. Better is the ball which falls closer to the center of a hole in the ground. Do you have any other suggestion on how I should approach this?

Comment: @ivaa14 Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm) you might want to use the speed of parent `p1` and the angle of parent `p2` and vice versa.

Comment: @Progman yes, it was my first idea to use the single-point crossover, but it seemed too simple